# How can I reach specific div in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plp page which are listed items. And user can favorite any item.
My problem is when the user favorite one item, I want to change star icon it should be show favorited.

Here my item structure:

```
<div class="product-tile-top">
                <div class="product-tile-top-inner tile-wishlist">
                    <span role="button" class="wish-list-icon" id="grc398342">
                      <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm pdp-wishlist-btn">
                          <span>
                              <img class="favorite" src="/_ui/responsive/common/images/favorite.svg" height="17px;">
                                  </span>
                      </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Every item has unique id like this:

```
<span role="button" class="wish-list-icon" id="grc398342">
```

So, I want to reach and change only this section when user favorite:

```
<span>
   <img class="favorite" src="/_ui/responsive/common/images/favorite.svg" height="17px;">
</span>
```

I changed my code like this but its not running?

```
var newURL = "/_ui/responsive/common/images/favorite-red.svg";
    function fav(elemId){
        $("#elemId").find(".favorite").attr("src", newURL)
    }
    $('#addBtn').click(function() {
        var listName = $('#listName').val();
        var productCode = $('#productCode').val();
        $('#notificationP').text('');
        if (listName.trim() == '') {
            $('#notificationP').text($('#nameValidate').val());
            return;
        }
        $('.loading-overlay').show();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : ACC.config.encodedContextPath + "/wishlist/add",
            data : 'productCode=' + productCode + '&listName=' + listName,
            success : function(loginPopup) {
                $('.loading-overlay').hide();
                if (loginPopup.code == '0' || loginPopup.code == '2') {
                    $('#notificationP').text($('#duplicate').val());
                } else if (loginPopup.code == '1') {
                    $('#notificationP').text($('#add').val());
                    fav(productCode);
                }
                else if(loginPopup.code == '3'){
                    $('#notificationP').text($('#maxProductsError').val()+' '+loginPopup.errorCodeMeg+')');
                }
                else {
                    $('#notificationP').text($('#globleError').val());
                }
            },
            error : function(error) {
                $('.loading-overlay').hide();
                $('#notificationP').text($('#globleError').val());
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I access this image?

Comment: can you tell me witch ajax is making the item as favorite because i dont see add button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Onclick` of the `div` invoke a function and push the `id` of the div. Using `children` get the span child and make changes

```js
function a(id) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(id).children[0].children[0];
  ele.style.color = "red";
  ele.children[0].setAttribute('url',"www.xyz.com")
  console.log(ele.children[0].getAttribute('url'))
}
```

```html
<div class="product-tile-top">
  <div class="product-tile-top-inner tile-wishlist">
    <span role="button" class="wish-list-icon" id="grc398342" onclick=a(this.id)>
      <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm pdp-wishlist-btn">
        <span>dd
            <img class="favorite" src="/_ui/responsive/common/images/favorite.svg" height="17px;">
         </span>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can ı use without function because ı use ajax call when the return success. I have to change img when the ajax call success ?

Comment: The ajax call will be happening on a trigger. I suppose it will happen on the click of the div. On function call get the id of the div and on success change the url

Comment: in your way, how can ı img src change? I can't reach when ı use ele.find()

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.find()` method on the passed element in jquery like this. We give `.find()` the class name of the image and then change `src` attribute of the image. In this example if you click on the icon it will change to a star.

```js
var newURL = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/start_53876-25533.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg";
function fav(elem){
  $(elem).find(".favorite").attr("src", newURL)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-tile-top">
  <div class="product-tile-top-inner tile-wishlist">
      <span role="button" class="wish-list-icon" id="grc398342" onclick="fav(this)">
        <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm pdp-wishlist-btn">
            <span>
                <img class="favorite" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/yellow-star-trail-set_23-2147739091.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg" height="17px;">
            </span>
        </div>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for your comment how to do this in ajax. You can return the item id in your ajax call and then access it like this

```js
var newURL = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/start_53876-25533.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg";
function fav(elemId){
  $("#elemId").find(".favorite").attr("src", newURL)
}

// your ajax call
$.ajax({
  url: "",
  data: { /*Your parameters*/},
  success: function(returnedData){
    fav(returnedData);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-tile-top">
  <div class="product-tile-top-inner tile-wishlist">
      <span role="button" class="wish-list-icon" id="grc398342">
        <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm pdp-wishlist-btn">
            <span>
                <img class="favorite" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/yellow-star-trail-set_23-2147739091.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg" height="17px;">
            </span>
        </div>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can ı use without function because ı use ajax call when the return success. I have to change img when the ajax call success ?

Comment: @oerbas I have added another piece of code to the answer, basically you have to return the id of the item of the span

Comment: thanks your help but its not running. I updated my code again like you do, can you help again?

Comment: @oerbas sorry. I made a mistake. I will correct it.